# Are there any access modifiers for static blocks in java

Tags: java

As we have access modifiers for methods and constructors, do we have it for static blocks? if yes what is the significance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there aren't any. And you can't call the static blocks either, so it wouldn't make much sense.

Answer (score 3):

The [Java Language Reference](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.7) says no too.

The definition of the syntax for a static initializer is:

> static *Block*

Nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 2):

Access modifiers (loosely speaking) tell you what you can do with class or instance members (such as methods and fields) - for example, who is allowed access them (or how you can access them, given who you are).  With a static initializer, you have neither a field nor a method - just some code to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have an access modifier for static blocks.

I'm assuming you want to write something like:

```
private static {
   // do something
}
```

which is semantically incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

How do you expect to access a static block? i think you can't call it directly, so why bother to have access modifiers?